# Haskell Maybe not working on higher order function

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I'm trying to make a function that takes in a string which is an operator and maybe returns a function. So that hopefully I could run the following command:

```
operationOn1 "+" 5
```

Which I hope would return 6.
This is my code:

```
add1 :: Integer -> Integer
add1 x = x + 1

sub1 :: Integer -> Integer
sub1 x = x - 1

operationOn1 :: String -> Maybe(Integer -> Integer)
operationOn1 "+" = Just add1
operationOn1 "-" = Just sub1
operationOn1 _ = Nothing
```

I'm too new to this to know what to google to find any help, all of the tutorials I can find about the maybe keyword don't go into higher order functions so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your code looks good to me. What don't you like about it?

Comment: You need to pay the function $5, and then it will work ;) `($5) <$> operationOn1 "+"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't immediately use something of type `Maybe (Integer -> Integer)` like you would use something of type `Integer -> Integer`. In other words, this line doesn't work:

```
λ operationOn1 "+" 5
--^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This part is of type `Maybe (Integer -> Integer)`.
--                 ^ Using it in this way is incorrect,
--                   since it is not of type `Integer -> Integer`.
```

In fact, if you read the error message, it tells you exactly this. **Always read the error message:**

```
error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer -> t’
                  with actual type ‘Maybe (Integer -> Integer)’
    • The function ‘operationOn1’ is applied to two arguments,
      but its type ‘String -> Maybe (Integer -> Integer)’ has only one
      In the expression: operationOn1 "+" 5
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = operationOn1 "+" 5
```

So, we need to deal with the `Maybe ...` 'wrapper' that is around the function we want to use.

There is an inbuilt function specifically to deal with this kind of situation, namely [`(<*>) :: (Applicative f) => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Maybe+%28a-%3Eb%29+-%3E+a+-%3E+Maybe+b), like so:

```
λ operationOn1 "+" <*> Just 5
Just 6
λ operationOn1 "-" <*> Just 4
Just 3
λ operationOn1 "what?" <*> Just 3
Nothing
```

If you don't know what an applicative functor is, I'd highly recommend reading the [LYAH chapter on functors, applicative functors, and monoids](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids).

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce your own helper function

```
($>) :: Maybe (a -> b) -> a -> Maybe b
($>) Nothing _ = Nothing
($>) (Just f) a = Just $ f a
```

and use it `operationOn1 "+" $> 5`